# Creating a violin plot with seaborn without x and y values but with hue

Tags: python, seaborn, violin-plot

I am trying to create a violin plot using seaborn.

My df looks like this:

```
drought
Out[65]:

            Dataset      TGLO       TAM      TAFR       TAA  Type
0         ACCESS1-0  0.181017  0.068988  0.166761  0.069303  AMIP
1         ACCESS1-3  0.109676 -0.001961 -0.008700  0.373162  AMIP
2           BNU-ESM  0.277070  0.272242  0.266324 -0.077017  AMIP
3             CCSM4  0.385075  0.258976  0.304438  0.211241  AMIP
...
21              CMAP  0.087274 -0.062214 -0.079958  0.372267   OBS
22               ERA  0.179999 -0.010484  0.134584  0.204052   OBS
23              GPCC  0.173947 -0.020719  0.021819  0.370157   OBS
24              GPCP  0.151394  0.036450 -0.021462  0.336876   OBS
25               UEA  0.223828 -0.018237  0.088486  0.398062   OBS
26              UofD  0.190969  0.094744  0.036374  0.310938   OBS
```

I want to have a split violin plot based on Type and this is the code I am using

```
sns.violinplot(data=drought, hue='Type', split=True)
```

And this is the error:

```
Cannot use `hue` without `x` or `y`
```

I do not have an x or y value because what I want is to have the columns as x , and the values in the rows as y.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to ignore the 'Dataset' column and have split violins for the 4 other columns?  In that case, you need to convert these 4 columns to ["long form"](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data) (via pandas' `melt()`).

Here is an example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

drought = pd.DataFrame({'Dataset': ["".join(np.random.choice([*'VWXYZ'], 5)) for _ in range(40)],
                        'TGLO': np.random.randn(40),
                        'TAM': np.random.randn(40),
                        'TAFR': np.random.randn(40),
                        'TAA': np.random.randn(40),
                        'Type': np.repeat(['AMIP', 'OBS'], 20)})
drought_long = drought.melt(id_vars=['Dataset', 'Type'], value_vars=['TGLO', 'TAM', 'TAFR', 'TAA'])
sns.set_style('white')
ax = sns.violinplot(data=drought_long, x='variable', y='value', hue='Type', split=True, palette='flare')
ax.legend()
sns.despine()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: violinplot with split=True from long form dataframe]

Comment: Thanks, @JohanC. I was looking for a plot precisely like this. It worked smoothly.

Comment: Seconded! Lovely solution.